# Slow Paypal NVP API

Tags: vb.net, paypal

I'm trying to interface my app to paypal account using NVP API.
All works fine but I find the paypal response time veeery slow, almost unusable.

If I query the last 100 transaction using the method "TransactionSearch" paypal takes 15 to 20 seconds to give a response.

The response worth only 25kB so I don't think it's a matter of amount of data.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

This is my code:

```
Dim param As New Specialized.NameValueCollection
param.Add("STARTDATE", "2017-01-1 0:0:0")

Dim response As String = getNVP("TransactionSearch", param)


 Private Function getNVP(ByVal method As String, Optional ByVal param As Specialized.NameValueCollection = Nothing) As String
    If param Is Nothing Then param = New Specialized.NameValueCollection
    Using client As New Net.WebClient
        param.Add("METHOD", method)
        param.Add("USER", APIuser)
        param.Add("PWD", APIpass)
        param.Add("SIGNATURE", APIsign)
        param.Add("VERSION", "204")
        Dim rbytes = client.UploadValues("https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp", "POST", param)
        Return Uri.UnescapeDataString((New System.Text.UTF8Encoding).GetString(rbytes))
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: In your request I am not seeing an `EndDate` time range for the `TransactionSearch` method although it is ***optional***. Could you see if that helps as I am not seeing anything wrong in your code you provided.

Comment: Tested right now adding end date but don't solve my problem.
It seems that the response time is proportional to the resulting transaction count. If I narrow the date span (to get less result), the response delay reduces but become even less efficient than before (due to the http overhead). 
For 10 transactions I mesured 2,5s delay.

Someone can confirm PayPal's API are so slow? If so I'll give up.

Comment: Yes, the PayPal APIs are notoriously slow on reads. Writes run pretty fast, but not on reads. I swear they feed hamsters to run that company's servers. You can also see this evident when you simply load a web page in their reporting. If I had reason to bet, I'd say that their database is heavily normalized, which makes for fast writes and slow reads.

Comment: I've also experienced this, and have found that limiting the transactions to only a few at a time is the only way to "speed it up." Is it feasible to split your queries for paged response? i.e. page 1 is records 1 - 5, page 2 is 6 - 10, etc

Comment: which country are you triggering requests from ?

Answer (score 0):

The TransactionSearch API is not a payment processing API, it's an auxiliary API of tangential importance to the bulk of what PayPal does, so it's never been particularly optimized.  If  you are concerned about performance, a much better solution would be to record all transactions to your own database.

If you need one-time history, that can be gotten from an activity CSV via the Reports tab in www.paypal.com

If you need a daily report of all activity in the PayPal account, large entities make use of PayPal's SFTP reports to get a dump: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/reports/